# "Dictionary" with multiple values for given key

Tags: php

How to make a "dictionary" in php which will contain many values for a single key?
With single values, I do a class with constants, e.g .:

```
class Formats {
     const big = 1;
     const small = 2;
}
```

and then in the code I use for example:

```
Formats::big
```

However, how to do it if I want a given format to contain, for example, dimensions?

In C #, I would do something like this:

```
   static class Formats
     {
         public static class Big
         {
             public static int id = 1;
             public static int width = 200;
             public static int height = 150;
         }

         public static class Small
         {
             public static int id = 2;
             public static int width = 100;
             public static int height = 50;
         }
     }
```

and used:

```
Formats.Big.height;
```

Thank you in advance :).

Answer (score 1):

What about an array?

```
class Formats {
     const big = array(
        "id" => 1,
        "width" => 200,
        "height" => 150
     );
}
```

Can then access with `Formats::big["height"]`